# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while executing .jar

Tags: java, opencv, intellij-idea, jar

I have created a .jar of my image processing project which runs on intellij idea.While running .jar using java -jar project.jar it outputs an error Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main. But when i extract the .jar and go to the inside and open the terminal and then run java sample.Main [sample is the package] , it works perfectly. I think problem may be the class path. How can i solve this.

Comment: Did you check the settings when you create the artifact (JAR) with IntelliJ or how do create the jar file?

Comment: Check if your JAR has `Main-Class` property set in manifest. If you want freely execute app from that jar take a look on [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).

Comment: I think i have solved this. [my_previous_question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411525/missing-javafx-application-class-sample-main/47551891#47551891)